# Plot a DataFrame over a range of time indices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am new to Python and pandas.

I have a dataset loaded into Python as a DataFrame. The index of the DataFrame are times of the format "2018-01-01 00:00:00". My dataset ranges from "2018-01-01 00:00:00" to "2018-12-31 23:59:59". The data column has a column name "X".

I can plot the entire dataset using matplotlib:

```
plt.plot(data.index, data["X"])
```

However, I want to plot different segments of the time series: 1 month, 6 months, 2 days, 3 seconds, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plot a month you could do

```
data.loc['2018-02',"X"].plot()
```

6 months

```
data.loc['2018-02':'2018-08',"X"].plot()
```

and the same logic applies for other ranges

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do one more processing step on your index to ensure you're dealing with datetime objects rather than strings.

```
new_data = (
    data
    .assign(datetime=lambda df: pandas.to_datetime(df.index))
    .set_index('datetime')
)

new_data["X"].plot()
```

This should get us really close to what you want, but i haven't tested it on data with your date format.